# How to download text file from web on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a young iphone dev who needs to download a .txt file from a web (I got a ftp sever) to update a small database on the device. Anyone could give me an advice of how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading it (see [Downloading to a Predetermined Destination](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839))

```
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://myftpserver/path/to/file.txt"]];
```

Reading it (see [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC))

```
float aFloat;
NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [theScanner scanFloat:&aFloat];
    // implementation continues...
}
```

Updating the Database, it all depends on what you are using for a  Database.  I would start with the [Core Data Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) docs

Answer (score 1):

You can use

NSDATA *data = [NSDATA dataWithContentOfURL:@"www.yourserver.com/abc.txt"];

and you can later store it in your documents directory

Answer (score -1):

I think using a NSURLDownload would be better as it is meant for it lol.

all you need:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839-BAJEAIEE

Comment: From that link: The NSURLDownload class is not available in iOS, because downloading directly to the file system is discouraged. Use the NSURLConnection class instead.